# DCEF3 “Incompatible types: method pointer and regular procedure” TCefFastStringVisitor.Create

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded, delphi-10.1-berlin, tchromium

I used in Delphi XE7 the following code to get frame source in DCEF3:

```
procedure TForm1.Chromium1LoadEnd(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser; const frame: ICefFrame; httpStatusCode: Integer);
var CefStringVisitor:ICefStringVisitor;
begin

    CefStringVisitor := TCefFastStringVisitor.Create(CallbackSource); //<--Error here
    frame.GetSource(CefStringVisitor);
end;


procedure TForm1.CallbackSource(const str: ustring);
begin
    //Do some work
end;
```

I migrated my project to Delphi XE 10.1 Berlin, and now the same code does not work. The following error occurs:

**Incompatible types: 'regular procedure and method pointer',**

In the following code snippet:

```
CefStringVisitor := TCefFastStringVisitor.Create(CallbackSource)
```

Comment: As it says, you can't provide a method pointer (a procedure of object) to something expecting a standalone (not attached to object) procedure. IOW, you can't pass `TForm1.CallbackSource` because it's a method pointer.

Comment: Thank you Ken White for reply. This is clear. But there is another way to make the code work.

Comment: Yes. Make the procedure standalone (not a member of TForm1).